# How to create a simple custom heatmap?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I want to create a Heatmap from pandas DataFrame `df`. The `df` has two columns:

```
name  test
aa    False
bb    False
cc    True
dd    False
```

The heatmap should include `name` values in X axis, and `test` values in Y axis. So, basically there should be 2 rows - False and True in Y axis. When `test` value is False, the False square is marked in red. When `test` value is True, the True square is marked in Green.

This is my current code:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

Index= df["name"].values
Cols = [True, False]
r = pd.DataFrame(df, index=Index, columns=Cols)
sns.heatmap(r, annot=True)
```

However this code does not work properly. How can I solve my task?

Comment: what exactly do you expect your heatmap looks like?

Comment: @QuangHoang: Please see the answer of Chris A This is what I was expecting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to reshape your `DataFrame` to plot it the way you want.

For example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df_new = df.set_index('name')['test'].astype(str).str.get_dummies().T

print(df_new)
name   aa  bb  cc  dd
False   1   1   0   1
True    0   0   1   0
```

Then you can use `seaborn.heatmap`:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(8, 4))
sns.heatmap(df_new, cmap='RdYlGn')
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what I was looking for. How can I control the color of black boxes and the size of a heatmap?

Comment: maybe try `cmap='PiYg'` ? may take a bit of experimenting

Comment: Size of heatmap can be controlled by passing `figsize` to `sns.heatmap`